# Finding/Printing out specific words starting with a specific letter

Tags: java, string, methods, static, static-methods

Here is the main:

```
public class MiscStringOperationsDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            // Test the wordCount method
            int numWords = MiscStringOperations.wordCount("There are five words here.");
            System.out.printf("Number of words: %d\n\n", numWords);

            // Test the arrayToString method
            char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
            String lettersToString = MiscStringOperations.arrayToString(letters);
            System.out.printf("The string is: %s\n\n", lettersToString);

            // Test the mostFrequent method
            char mostFrequentChar = MiscStringOperations.mostFrequent("aababbcddaa");
            System.out.printf("The most-frequent character is: %c\n\n", mostFrequentChar);

            // Test the beginWithB method
            String wordList = MiscStringOperations.beginWithB(
                            "Batman enjoyed some blueberries and a bacon burger in the Batmobile.");
            System.out.printf("The list of words is: %s\n\n", wordList);
    }
}
```

All of the methods are in another class. I am struggling with last method which is the beginWithB method. I have everything else working. Here's what I have so far for this method:

```
 public static String beginWithB(String wordlist) {
    String myStr = wordlist;
    for(String b: myStr.split(" ")){
        if(b.startsWith("b")||b.startsWith("B")){
            System.out.print(b);
        }   
    }
```

I am struggling to find a way to return the words that start with a "b" or "B" to the main. Any ideas? (And yes, I have to do it this way).

Comment: You are just printing the value of `b`. You need to add them to a list and return the list of strings that start with b. `wordList` should actually be a `List`, not a `String`

Comment: What are you returning form `beginWithB()` ? is that your full method ? as you want a list of string don't you need to `string[]` from that method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method looks fine to me, you just need to make a string as you are returning a String. (see the code bellow)

**CODE**

```
public static String beginWithB(String wordlist) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String myStr = wordlist;
    for (String b : myStr.split(" ")) {
        if (b.startsWith("b") || b.startsWith("B")) {
            sb.append(b + " ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The list of words is: Batman blueberries bacon burger Batmobile.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know i had to add the toString() part.